# AWS Lambda API Gateway REST end point No method found matching route for http method GET

Tags: spring-boot, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I have Spring boot application uploaded on AWS Lambda via S3.

As per my requirement, I have to use this as API Gateway end point. So, I tried adding it like below on the Lambda console:

I clicked on "Add Trigger"
Chose "API Gateway"
Create a New API
Selected "REST API"
Security is "Open"
Added

I got an API API Gateway REST end point, when i tested using Postman, i got error: `"message": "No method found matching route mmtDemoFunction/searchAll for http method GET."`

Spring boot code:

```
public class AWSLambdaHandler implements RequestStreamHandler {
    private SpringBootLambdaContainerHandler<AwsProxyRequest, AwsProxyResponse> handler;

    public AWSLambdaHandler() throws ContainerInitializationException {
        handler = (SpringBootLambdaContainerHandler<AwsProxyRequest, AwsProxyResponse>) new SpringBootProxyHandlerBuilder()
                .springBootApplication(AWSTestApplication.class)
                .defaultProxy()
                .asyncInit()
                .buildAndInitialize();
    }

    @Override
    public void handleRequest(InputStream inputStream, OutputStream outputStream, Context context)
            throws IOException {
        handler.proxyStream(inputStream, outputStream, context);
    }
}
```

RestController:

```
@RestController

public class AWSTestController {

        @Autowired
        private MMTServiceDAO mmtServiceDAO;

        @CrossOrigin(origins = "*")
        @GetMapping("/searchAll")
        public List<MMTData> searchAll() {

            List<MMTData> dataList = mmtServiceDAO.findAll();
            return dataList;
         }

        @CrossOrigin(origins = "*")
        @GetMapping("/searchDataByMember/{memberno}")
        public List<MMTData> searchDataByMember(@PathVariable Integer memberno) {

           List<MMTData> dataList = mmtServiceDAO.findDataByMemberNo(memberno);
            return dataList;
        }
}
```

API Gateway:

```
[mmtFunction-API](https://us-east-2.console.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/home?region=us-east-2#/apis/7ocfwgjy5b/resources/ymsdok/methods/ANY)
arn:aws:execute-api:us-east-2:383322123415:7ocfwgjy5b/*/*/mmtFunction
API endpoint: https://7ocfwgjy5b.execute-api.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/default/mmtFunction
Details
API type: REST
Authorization: NONE
Method: ANY
Resource path: /mmtFunction
Service principal: apigateway.amazonaws.com
Stage: default
Statement ID: lambda-937e9b59-282a-4ff8-af14-717eaa623d85
```

Spring boot code:

public class AWSLambdaHandler implements RequestStreamHandler {
private SpringBootLambdaContainerHandler<AwsProxyRequest, AwsProxyResponse> handler;

```
public AWSLambdaHandler() throws ContainerInitializationException {
    handler = (SpringBootLambdaContainerHandler<AwsProxyRequest, AwsProxyResponse>) new SpringBootProxyHandlerBuilder()
            .springBootApplication(AWSTestApplication.class)
            .defaultHttpApiV2Proxy()
            .asyncInit()
            .buildAndInitialize();
}

@Override
public void handleRequest(InputStream inputStream, OutputStream outputStream, Context context)
        throws IOException {
    handler.proxyStream(inputStream, outputStream, context);
}
```

}

@RestController

public class AWSTestController {

```
    @Autowired
    private MMTServiceDAO mmtServiceDAO;

    @CrossOrigin(origins = "*")
    @GetMapping("/searchAll")
    public List<MMTData> searchAll() {

        List<MMTData> dataList = mmtServiceDAO.findAll();
        return dataList;
     }

    @CrossOrigin(origins = "*")
    @GetMapping("/searchDataByMember/{memberno}")
    public List<MMTData> searchDataByMember(@PathVariable Integer memberno) {

       List<MMTData> dataList = mmtServiceDAO.findDataByMemberNo(memberno);
        return dataList;
    }
```

}

Could someone please help how to solve this issue?

Comment: I solved missing authentication token error (my question was earlier like this, and i am modified with current error now) by adding access key, secret key in Authorization section of Postman. I get another error: 
{
    "message": "No method found matching route mmtDemoFunction/searchAll for http method GET."
}
But, I have searchAll() method in my uploaded spring boot jar file which runs as Lambda function. Earlier, I was able to test like Function url with /searchAll GET method successfully.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your AWS Lambda install log:

```
[mmtFunction-API](https://us-east-2.console.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/home?region=us-east-2#/apis/7ocfwgjy5b/resources/ymsdok/methods/ANY)
arn:aws:execute-api:us-east-2:383322123415:7ocfwgjy5b/*/*/mmtFunction
API endpoint: https://7ocfwgjy5b.execute-api.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/default/mmtFunction
Details
API type: REST
Authorization: NONE
Method: ANY
Resource path: /mmtFunction
Service principal: apigateway.amazonaws.com
Stage: default
Statement ID: lambda-937e9b59-282a-4ff8-af14-717eaa623d85
```

the correct path to your new endpoint is **/mmtFunction/searchAll**.

From your error message ("No method found matching route mmtDemoFunction/searchAll for http method GET."), you look to be using incorrect app context. It should be mntFunction based on the way your lambda was installed.